# Current list of supportedMethods for the W3C PaymentRequest API

Tags: javascript, paypal, stripe-payments, square, payment-request-api

[This](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/payments/basics/payment-method-basics) is the only reference I could find on the web listing URL based PSPs adhering to the the PaymentRequest API. Does anyone have a more recent or comprehensive one?
This is the list in that link: -

Existing payment method identifiers
Google Pay (https://google.com/pay)
Apple Pay (https://apple.com/apple-pay)
Samsung Pay (https://spay.samsung.com)

I also believe Alipay suports the Payment Request API. How/Where do I find out who currently supports it?

Comment: I'm not sure what it is you're trying to ask here?

Comment: Are you asking for browser support or for payment service providers, supporting it in general?

Comment: Payment service providers. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I would assume that list is a ~complete list, based on the information in the page.